# Log4j2 Custom appender: ERROR Attempted to append to non-started appender

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I have created a custom appender in log4j2. While using the custom appender, I am getting the following error: "ERROR Attempted to append to non-started appender". Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Log4j 2 checks for each log event that the appender is in a useable state. The error you are seeing is that Log4j detects that the appender is not ready to be used.

Some appenders need to do preparation before they can be used. The `start()` lifecycle method is the place where appenders can do initialization. Log4j will not route events to an appender that is not in a STARTED state.

If your appender is added by configuration, Log4j will call the lifecycle method. If your  appender extends AbstractAppender, this will update the state and should be sufficient. Otherwise take a look at the lifecycle state management in AbstractAppender.

If you configure in code you may need to call start() explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @Remko. I have extended AbstractAppender and have configured  the appender using XML. I will investigate the start() method invocation as per your advice. Thanks.

Comment: @Remko Popma In case of multiple threads, explicitly calling start() method also leads to this issues. Should one put start() call in synchronized block ?

Comment: I don’t think that applications should call `start()` manually. Custom plugins implementing `LifeCycle` may _implement_ this method. The log4j framework will call the start method.

Comment: i.e. you probably need to call `super.start()` if you have overridden it like I did